# click on edit button container expand and show options

Tags: flutter

[container where I want clicking in edit button container expand in height and show option when I click on edit button container will close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFA05.png)

Comment: You can achieve this with expansiontile widget..

Comment: Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

Comment: Spend 5 mins to understand this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RaNa please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set bool for expand or not in edit button.

You can follow the bellow code.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

bool isEdit;

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    isEdit = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isEdit = !isEdit;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("Edit"),
                ),
              ),
              isEdit
                  ? ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        maxWidth: double.infinity,
                        minHeight: 0.0,
                        maxHeight: 200.0,
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        color: Color(0xffff0000),
                        child: TextField(),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```